# gridview inside gridview... forum functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, forum

I have a question regarding **gridview inside gridview's**  **selection functionality**.
I am trying to achieve **forum** functionality.. i.e. A thread is posted and people comment on that thread . one can quote from earlier posted comments, add his opinions and finally make his comment.

I am binding the inside gridview's data on RowDataBound event of parent gridview. In database I have a *Parent ID* columns which have the ID of the Thread post on which the reply is made.
so far simple reply(without quoting any of earlier comments) functionality is working just fine.

Now I am having an issue on quoting scenario.. I've a button inside the inner gridview(gridview2)'s item template..upon clicked which should give me the ID of that post. but i am unable to figure out any solution yet..as gridview2 is not accessible in .cs file

Comment: nvm .. I got it working by some hit and trail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly access any control inside the gridview from code behind. You have to first make the object of that control.

```
GridView GridView2=(GridView)GridView1.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("GridView2");
```

Something like this.
Refer this:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189997/Gridview-inside-Gridview-in-asp-net-Csharp. It may help you.

Comment: Thanks Priya for quick reply... I know that  .. 
Actually i was calling both, the button(Quote) click event and selectedindexchanged event.. removed the buttoncicked event and Now working the way it is supposed to be.. 
I already had this in gvselectionchangeevent ..

    GridView gvTR = new GridView();
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvThreadsMain.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                         gvTR = (GridView)row.FindControl("gvThreadsReplies");
            }
        }

Anyways thankyou again :)